# Insert Query to insert between two dates

Tags: java, ms-access, netbeans, insert

I am developing leave management system in java netbeans.. i want to insert all leaves between two dates like below:
Employee No.: '108'
Employee Name: 'Wasif'
Date From: '4/19/2023'
To: '4/30/2023'
How can i insert this record multiple times according to leave dates? (One date per record)

I have tried but m unable to get fruitful result

Comment: Perhaps one or more of [these questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+ms-access+site:stackoverflow.com) can help you - but you need to show us your code, otherwise. See [ask] and [mre] for more guidance.

Comment: The question is tagged as a Java question, and mentions Java - not VBA. I don't think the dupe target is directly relevant (except maybe as an alternative approach).  @June7

Comment: Ooops, I zoned on Access tag. However, I am guessing some sort of loop still needed.